# How to filter out element with its content in CKE5 data

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

Let's imagine there is initial data for CKEditor 5 such as:

```
const data = `<style type="text/css" style="display:none">
                <!-- .foo { color: red} -->
              </style>
              <div>test</div>`;
```

I aim to get just `<div>test</div>` as output of CKEditor5. `GHS` plugin is not used, so, all unsupported elements are stripped out according to the set of included features to my build. In my case, `<style>` is out, that's fine.

Output of CKE5:

```
'<p>&lt;!-- .foo { color: red} --&gt;&nbsp;</p><p>test</p>'
```

Basically, from what I see, it just replaces unsupported `<style>` HTML element with `<p>` element. However, I wish to completely remove it with all content. We might need to leverage some kind of data pipeline API...

Hence, how to filter out `<style>` element **with** its internal content **before** CKE5 pass incoming data through conversions and its model?